# Show different thumbnail image set for each color picked in configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, magento-community, product-images, thumbnail

Hi everybody (first post here), I've been trying Magento 1.9 display a different set of thumbnail images for every option in the color swatch, in a configurable product, but with no success.

For example, there are different colors for a single shoes model, (a single product) and for every color, there is a set of five photographs (different perspectives, of course), so I associated those photographs to a single product, and then I associated that single product to a configurable product (with just a single picture).

It doesn't work. Just one picture for every single color is showed as a base image in the product page, but always the thumbnail corresponding with the configurable product.

In the Magento 1.9 demo database an opposite approach is used (which I guess the right path): all the product with different colors goes with configurable product, while the single procuct has just one image... but it doesn't work either to my case.

What I expect is that Magento display the five pictures from the single product with a specific color picked by the user (in the same way as Amazon does it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That feature is not available in Magento 1.9.1. Only one image can be set per color just like in the demo. If you want a set of images per color to switch after you select an option, I suggest you use an extension like Amasty Color Swatches Pro or Aheadworks Product Color Swatches.

Or let's just wait for Magento's new update. Maybe they will include that feature in their next release.

Comment: Only two extensions available... and both are commercials?

Comment: just a dumb question: if the swatches feature is disable, there's a way that I can see (in the configurable product page) more than one thumbnail for every single product? cause I've been trying with no success.

Comment: More than one thumbnail for every single product... I think I didn't get the question you're trying to ask.  :D You mean you want to add multiple images in one product option? Still not possible as of the moment.

Comment: Yes, in the product page two kind of images are seen: base and thumbnail images. I want the thumbnail images displayed match with the color selected in the color swatch by the customer (obviously, the simple product should have many pictures associated and the configurable have just one, as the opposite found in the demo database). 
I'll have to install the Extreme Magento Swatches extension (which I don't know if it's compatible with 1.9 version).

Comment: there are also free modules in magentocommerce.com/magento-connect, but I don't recommend them. :)